# How to argue that if we could solve the halting problem, then we could solve busy beaver?

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines, computer-science-theory

This is one of the tasks of my assignment. I have a Turing machine simulation which can simulate a [busy beaver function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver). I have done some research about proving this problem, but still don't get it so I guess maybe you can help me here.  A good source for me to go to or example of how to argue this would be good.

Comment: If your problem is to prove that solving the halting problem allows us to solve the busy beaver problem, then asking for an "example of how to argue this" is explicitly asking for the answer to your homework. This is often called "cheating". You have just cheated. This is a very straight forward problem that applies the definitions of the halting problem and the busy beaver problem directly, and you haven't even worked hard enough to see that. Congratulations.

Comment: I'm actually asking for help.Not asking for answer if you can read it properly!My real task is different from i'm asking here.If you don't answer,please don't make such a comments.Thank you.

Comment: I read it just fine. 1) Your title: "How to argue that if we could solve the halting problem, then we could solve busy beaver?". Your request: An "example of how to argue this". An example argument is an argument and is hence an answer. 2) You say that this argument is a task on your assignment and not that it is _different_ from a task on your assignment. So you have indeed asked for a solution to your assigned task, whereas the point of the task was probably for you to think about the problem for yourself. This may not complete your entire assignment so I can see why you think it's 'help'.

Comment: I guess you don't have teaching skill that's why you don't get it.If someone asks you for a particular problem and you answered but he/she still can't get it.Haven't you tried to explain them by giving them an example.For example, how does stack works? you may say it works just as you stack a book so the top of the stack get poped off first when it's insert last.That's an example of an explanation.Anyway,even if someone is asking for an answer so what's your problem?don't answer if you don't want.A person like you if someone is asking for help, you just say keep google it!that's your lesson.

Comment: Wow, you're totally right. Thanks for teaching me this important lesson. You win!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BB function is defined to be the maximum number of steps a Turing machine of a particular size can carry out and still halt. (Another way of putting it is that all Turing machines of size x will either halt in less than BB(x) steps, or run forever).

Assuming you have a Turing machine of complexity x, then you could determine whether it would halt or not by letting it run for BB(x) time-steps - if it hadn't halted by then, then by definition it never will.

Equally, if you could solve the halting problem, you could evaluate all possible Turing machines of size x, eliminate those that don't halt, and take BB(x) to be the maximum of the run times of the remainders.

Of course, BB(x) is non-computable - and in fact grows faster than any possible computable function you could name - hence it cannot even be approximated.

Comment: Awesome.Now I got an idea.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can find the proof you seek [here](http://www.earlham.edu/~peters/courses/logsys/turing2.htm), below the proof that the Busy Beaver problem is uncomputable.